# Trying to remove references to DLLs and they keep resurfacing in Temporary ASP.NET files?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to clear out some old DLLs that are no longer used by my MVC3 ASP.NET C# application. 
I used to have :

```
using mySpecialDll;
```

type code, and I have deleted these lines or commented them out. I have rebuilt the application and the solution. I have removed these extra dlls from the bin. However when I run the application I get a compile error and the compiled page in Temporary ASP.NET files is shown with the old uncommented "using mySpecialDLL;" line. I have tried to delete all the folders in the Temporary ASP.NET files root folder, but to no available.

Also the mySpecialDll is not referenced by the application.

It must be referenced from somewhere, but I am confused on this one.

So how do I stop old code using old DLLs being used and referenced.

Thanks

EDIT:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a23524eb\66db42a8\App_Web_index.cshtml.8ea7e316.-7paqjsj.0.cs(27,26): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'mySpecialDLL' does not exist in the namespace 'Org.Myapplication' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Did you remove the reference from the project references folder and/or the web.config file?

Comment: I removed the DLLS from the references link in Visual Studio and WEb.Config. I "removed" the link. Perhaps I should have used Resharper's "safe delete". Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: Could have found the issue. May have been some hidden GAC references in Web.config. Just checking

Comment: Think I have sorted it now thanks... Was the web.Config.

Comment: Think I will use Safe Delete in future !!

Comment: Quite happy to close this now, so if you wish to write answer then I can award. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remove the reference from the project references folder and/or the web.config file?

Comment: I did, and i'm still getting this problem, any further help you could offer @Dark Falcon?